Forces of Two Rifles on Shoulder Mechanics
The problem is - "Two identical bullets are fired from a heavy and a light rifle with the same force. Which rifle hurts the shoulder more?"
The solution given was -
Let $F$ be the force on the bullet by the rifles. By Newton's Third Law, the force on the rifles opposite to the bullet's direction will also be $F$ and since $m$ $\propto$ $\frac{1}{a}$, the lighter rifle would be propelled back with greater acceleration hurting the shoulder more.
However I think that the answer is both rifles will hurt the same. The logic I used is that since the rifles move backward due to the force F, we will experience the force F on our shoulders on both rifles.
Please do correct me if I am wrong and provide an explanation

If you ever shoot a high powered rifle or a shotgun, you'll quickly learn to hold it firmly against your shoulder when you pull the trigger. That way, you and the gun will both be "propelled back" together, and the butt of the gun will not hammer on your shoulder.

My practical experience: I have fired a 7 pound mass, 20 gauge shotgun in the past.  The mass of the shotgun was so small that the recoil from a fairly small shotgun shell was VERY sharp and quick.  You can believe that small mass rifles do indeed put more recoil force on your shoulder than more massive rifles.


The logic I used is that since the rifles move backward due to the
force F, we will experience the force F on our shoulders on both
rifles.

The equal and opposite forces $F$ between the rifle and the bullet per Newton's 3rd law applies to the rifle and the bullet, not necessarily to the person.
For conservation of momentum, the lighter (lower mass) rifle will have a higher recoil velocity than the heaver (higher mass) rifle. Since kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, the lighter rifle will have greater kinetic energy when it impacts the shoulder.
Per the work energy theorem the net work done (average impact force times stopping distance) on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Thus, for the same stopping distance, the average impact force against the shoulder will be greater for the lighter rifle than the heavier rifle.
Hope this helps.

Are you saying that the same force acts for longer in the case of the lighter rifle?

@Chinmay No. I'm saying  a greater force needs to be exerted by the shoulder on the lighter rifle to stop it  because its kinetic energy is greater.  Per Newton's 3rd law that is the same force that the rifle exerts on the shoulder.

the lighter rifle need not have greater K.E as K.E depends on mass as well

@Chinmay Yes, but KE varies only linearly with mass whereas it varies as the square of the velocity. So  the lighter rifle will have greater KE.

Oh ok thanks for the clarification

@Chinmay Let's say the heavier rifle has mass of 2M and the lighter rifle of mass M. For conservation of momentum of the bullet-rifle if the velocity of the heavier rifle is V than the velocity of the lighter rifle is 2V. The KE of  the lighter rifle is  then $\frac{1}{2}M(2V)^2=2MV^2$. The KE of the heavier rifle is $\frac{1}{2}MV^{2}$.

one more thing, this argument depends on the stopping distance being same

@Chinmay Sure, but its a reasonable assumption that the shooter won't move much  given a mass much greater than the rifle and the rifle but  won't penetrate the shoulder very far given it is mostly bone and skin.  Couple this to the fact that in my example the KE of the lighter rifle is 4 x that of the heavy rifle.

If we don't assume that, could my answer be correct?

No because your answer is based on an incorrect (yet common) of application of Newton's 3rd law.  $F$ in your example refers to the force between the rifle and the bullet, not between the person (shoulder) and the rifle.

Let two Rifles A and B with mass M1 and M2 respectively and M2>M1
And also let velocity of rifles just after bullet was shot was V1 and V2 respectively
If a bullet of mass m was shot from both the rifles and attains a velocity v , we can apply conservation of momentum as there is no external force applying on the direction of motion of bullet
Conserving momentum -
For rifle A => M1 x V1 = m x v
For rifle B => M2 x V2 = m x v
Dividing both the equations since m and v for both equations are same we get
M1 x V1 = M2 x V2
We have assumed that M2 is greater than M1, so V2 will be less than V1
That means just after shooting the bullet the lighter rifle will gain higher velocity that the heavier rifle
The pain in shoulder is due to impulse
Now from impulse equation Force average = (Mo x Vo)/change in Time
Here the Mo can be M1 or M2, Vo can be V1 or V2
And from momentum conservation M1 x V1 = M2 x V2, so the impulse will be same
So feeling the impulse from both rifles is same, but we feel jerk which is d2v/dt2, since the velocity of rifle A is more we feel more push from lighter rifle
There can be multiple answers of this, as there are lot of factors affecting this, I am just assuming after shooting the velocity of bullet in both rifles are same...
There can be multiple answers of this since the conditions of the forces and velocities aren't known

You said that the pain in shoulder is due to impulse and later said the impulse is same, which implies both will hurt equally, doesn't it?

From the last few sentences of my answer "There can be multiple answers of this, as there are lot of factors affecting this, I am just assuming after shooting the velocity of bullet in both rifles are same...
There can be multiple answers of this since the conditions of the forces and velocities aren't known"

Haven't we given enough constraints to solve it? Forces are equal and the bullets are identical. Plus the velocities aren't equal, but the momenta are.

On what basis are you saying forces are equal, many factors affect this like the impulse of trigger to the bullet shell, the mass of trigger, the shape and size of gun etc, but if we simply assume the velocities of bullets after shooting is same we will feel more push due to jerk ( d2v/dt2) not due to impulse

Question states the forces are equal

Yes, as F=ma, and you don't have acceleration,mass,velocity of bullet
